# Not sure why my server is timing out...

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I currently launched my site live but am unsure as to why I am getting a POST timeout from jquery, meaning the POST has not even been sent... the site is live at http://lgavra.com/music#search I am clueless as to the ways to solve this issue, and have not found anything decent describing it. I am using backbone.js and node.js on the back end for this. It works pretty fast for the first search or two but then times out for the following 2-3 that are because it is taking longer than 30 seconds...Let me know if you need to see any code unsure of what to show...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are clicking `Search` button you are calling like this.

```
this.model.save({channel: e("#channel").val(),week: e("#week").val(),year: e("#year").val(),filter: e("#filter").val()}, {success: e.proxy(this.storeMusic, this)})
```

This is wrong, if you want to get data you should use `model.fetch`. Something like below.

```
this.model.fetch(
{data: {
         channel: e("#channel").val(),
         week: e("#week").val(),
         year: e("#year").val(),
         filter: e("#filter").val()
       }, 
 success: function () {}
})
```

Comment: thanks a lot this helped, I actually changed it on my site to a get, also, do you know by chance how I can trigger an event before the success, or to somehow say if a get response has been made I want to create a loading screen but not sure how to include it

Comment: Use [$.ajaxStart](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) to show loading.... message and use [$.ajaxComplete](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/) to hide it.